# jQuery synchronize animations jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have fixed header, that should disappear on button click.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-container">
        <header class="header">
           header
        </header>
        <div class="sidebar">
            sidebar
         </div>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page">
                <button>hide header</button>
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bssic CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.page-container, .page-wrapper{
    min-height: 400px;
   height: 100%; 
}
.header, .sidebar{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.header{
   width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    z-index: 90; 
}
.sidebar{
    top: 65px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.page{
    top: 65px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I created some JQuery code that animate header `height: 0;`and sidebar and page top property to 0. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2h1xopn/24/) The problem is that the animations work asynchronously. The header disappear, then the content and sidebar go up. can someone say, how I can synchronize the animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused header animation configuration a little. `duration` and `queue` go into separate object as the second parameter. It should be:

```
$(".header").css('overflow', 'hidden').animate({height: 0}, {
    duration: 200,
    queue: false
});
```

and

```
$(".header").css('overflow', 'initial').animate({height: '65px'}, {
    duration: 200,
    queue: false
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r2h1xopn/25/

**Bonus.** Since it's 2014 you can also use CSS animations instead.

```
.header, .sidebar {
    /* ... */
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
.page-container.header-closed .header {
    height: 0;
}
.page-container.header-closed .sidebar,
.page-container.header-closed .page {
     top: 0;
}
```

and then very simple JS to trigger it:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.page-container').toggleClass('header-closed');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r2h1xopn/27/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
}, { duration: 200, queue: false});
```

with

```
, duration: 200, queue: false });
```